# Why does Uglifyjs report "condition always false" here?

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

When I run the following code through the webpack UglifyJs plugin:

```
...
console.log('url: '+this.url);
let url = this.url;
let tags = []
while (true) {
    let i = url.indexOf('?tag=');
    if (i < 0) break;
    url = url.substring(i+5);
    let j = url.indexOf('?tag=');
    let tag = j < 0 ? url : url.substring(0,j);
    tags.push(tag); 
}
if (tags.length === 0) {   // UglifyJs reports  "condition always false" 
    ...
```

UglifyJs reports that the 'condition is always false' i.e. the tags array can never be empty, and kindly proceeds to remove the subsequent code.

Wtf? Clearly if the url contains no '?tag=' instance, the tags array will be empty.  If I refactor the above to be instead:

```
function getTags(url)
    let tags = []
    while (true) {
        let i = url.indexOf('?tag=');
        if (i < 0) break;
        url = url.substring(i+5);
        let j = url.indexOf('?tag=');
        let tag = j < 0 ? url : url.substring(0,j);
        tags.push(tag); 
    }
    if (tags.length === 0) {  //  no warning here from uglifyJs - why??
        console.log("no tags");
    }
    return tags;
}

....
console.log('url: '+this.url);
let url = this.url;
let tags = getTags(url);
if (tags.length === 0) {  //  no problems now
```

it now reports no problems.

I am really hoping someone can explain how and why UglifyJs might actually be correct here, because otherwise it is demonstrably introducing bugs into my code and will have to be removed forthwith.

Thanks in advance.